# Two different symlinks to the `make` binary: Why different results on invocation?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make, tmux

Setup: macOS, bash, inside tmux. I use `make` installed via homebrew.
When running `make` with my Makefile, I get

```
protoc -I=foo/bar/proto --cpp_out=foo/bar/proto foo/bar/proto/foo.proto
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo/bar/proto/foo.pb.h', needed by 'proto'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

When I instead run `gmake`, the program is successful:

```
protoc -I=foo/bar/proto --cpp_out=foo/bar/proto foo/bar/proto/foo.proto
protoc -I=foo/bar/proto --python_out=foo/bar/proto foo/bar/proto/foo.proto
```

But the binaries are exactly the same:

```
$> readlink -f `which make`
/usr/local/Cellar/make/4.2.1_1/bin/gmake
$> readlink -f `which gmake`
/usr/local/Cellar/make/4.2.1_1/bin/gmake
```

How is this possible?

---

It was suggested that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194957/what-is-the-difference-between-gmake-and-make) is a duplicate, which doesn't seem to be the case. I am aware, that the system-`make` is not necessarily GNU `make` or not a current version. But as proven above, the two commands **refer to the exact same binary**.

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't find it defined in its man, but it according to the above QA gmake is part of the tools that behave differently depending on how they have been invoked. Typical example is `bash` which can be invoked as `sh` to execute in a POSIX-compatible environment.

Comment: @Aaron I don't understand why that question refers to the same problem, since both commands in my case are symlinks to the same binary.

Comment: In the other question (and in my `bash`/`sh` sample) there's also a single executable that can be called by two different names. The point is that the executable is capable to identify which name is has been called with and behave differently. In your case your makefile must been relying on GNU make syntax's which would be disabled when you invoke GNU Make through `make` rather than `gmake`

Comment: But GNU `make` does *not* disable GNU Make extensions when you invoke it simply as `make`. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144424/restricting-gnu-make-to-posix-make-behaviour

Comment: @Aaron If that's true (the q itself does not comment on whether it's actually the same binary), I assume there's no way to turn off that behaviour? Seems crazy to me that the behaviour of a program is not 100% specified by the binary itself and what config it reads, but by the name it's called.

Comment: I think I jumped to conclusions, while I'm pretty sure the executables in the linked question are the same (they report the same implementation when called with `--version`) I guess the accepted answer only meant to mention using different implementations, rather than using different ways to call GNU make for different behaviours. I've retracted my close vote, and I suggest you use `type gmake` & `type make` to make sure there's no alias or function that explains the different behaviour (`which` only resolves elements of `$PATH` and would miss them)

Comment: @Aaron You're actually right, the problem was that I had an `alias make='make -j4'` defined. If you could describe why exactly that would cause a problem, you could make that an answer.

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with the makefile itself that makes it unable to be run in parallel then, you find quite a few examples with a "make parallel fail" websearch, but you won't be able to get a definite answer without posting your makefile